# Phonegap API notification and InAppBroswer can't work together

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I am now using phonegap 2.4.0 and it provided a new [InAppBroswer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) API.

The InAppBroswer works great but it makes the [Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) API fail to work.

I am also using the Push notification plugin , i confirm that it receive the message but it just fail to call the javascript in phonegap if the InAppBroswer is on.

Is there anyone are also facing this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InAppBrowser does not have the native integration that is available in the PhoneGap view.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to show notification on a external website, its there any possible solution?

Comment: depending on the page that you see in the InAppBrowser you could use the fragment part of the url. whenever you have a notification you update the url `{yourUrl}#notification={notification}`, then you monitor for Url changes in phone gap and whenever you receive a notification you handle that on PhoneGap side.